# Multicategories and Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

So... I was reading Tom Leinster's "*Higher Operads, Higher Categories*" and have 2 questions concerning compositions in a multicategory. He uses this "diagram" to denote the composition: [image: 1]]

You can also use graphs to denote morphisms and compositions in a multicategory. So here are my questions:

1. What are the benefits of using graphs to denote morphisms and compositions?
2. How would this composition look in terms of diagrams? Perhaps something like this? [image: 2]]

P.S.: I apologize for bad English and the second picture was made on paint, lol.

Comment: Remarks: (0) while usually being hyper-critical w.r.t. English, I did not find (upon reading this once), a reason for why you say "bad English"; there seem not to be any mistakes. (1) I think the question is vague and undefined. For example, you simply say "You can also use graphs to denote morphisms and compositions in a multicategory." without giving any explanation. What sense of "You can" do you mean? Do you mean "I know a reference which does."? Do you mean "I can do this?" I don't know a reference which uses 'graphs' (in the sense of 'irreflexive symmetric binary relation on a set')[..]

Comment: [..] to define operads. One problen is that the very point of many such definitions is that they are intended to *not* depend on an 'underlying set', while any  (graph-theoretic) 'graph' is a structure on a **set**. Roughly, the answer to 1. could be "There aren't any  'benefits' if generality is your goal' the might be 'benefits' if you like to use specific features of some specific set."

Comment: It may also help you to point out the following: it is a usual, somewhat illusory, and somewhat 'black-and-white' distinction, conceptually *very useful*, to always **distinguish between 'formulas' and 'models in a topos' (e.g.: in the topos of sets). Applied to you question, your 'Figure 2-B' is an axiom consisting of *formulas**, while a 'graph' is a **model (in the topos of sets) of the axioms of graph theory**. So if one takes your question literally, you seem to try to describe operads via a model*, which seems (to me) a **misguided pursuit you should perhaps not pursue further**.